# Connect docker compose containers without links

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

At above official docker document, I found the part

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

> Each container can now look up the hostname web or db and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, **web’s application code could connect to the URL postgres://db:5432** and start using the Postgres database.

So I understood this paragraph that I can connect docker containers each other without `links:` or `networks:` explicitly. because above `docker-compose.yml` snippet doesn't have `links` or `networks:` part. and the document say **web’s application code could connect to the URL postgres://db:5432**

So I tried to test simple docker-compose with nodejs `express`, `mongodb` together using above way. I thought I can connect `mongodb` in express app with just `mongodb://mongo:27017/myapp` But I cannot connect mongodb in express container. I think I followed docker's official manual but I don't know why it's not working. Of course I can connect mongodb using `links:` or `networks:` But I heard links is depreciated and I cannot find the proper way to use `networks:`

I think I might be misunderstood, Please fix me.
Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  app: 
    container_name: node
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

In express app, I connect to mongodb with

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017/myapp', {
    useMongoClient: true
});
// also doesn't work with mongodb://mongo/myapp
```

Plus) Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.17-alpine3.9
ENV NODE_ENV development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package*.json", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
    python \
    make \
    g++ \
    && npm install \
    && apk del build-dependencies
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

Comment: make sure that mongodb is up and accepting connection before that connect made from the app

Comment: @LinPy Yes, I guess that was an issue. node is started before mongo launched. how to fix it?

Comment: see this : https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: @LinPy Wow, that solves my problem! THanks!!

Comment: Also every docker image inside a container see's all the other machine ports,.  So unless your also wanting to expose `mongo` you don't even need -> `ports:  - '27017:27017'`

Comment: @Keith Wow, I deleted it and it still works. Every docker images inside a docker-compose.yml see all the other machine ports...that's coool

Answer (score -1):

If you want to connect mongo with local then you should have to select network mode.

docket-compose.yml file content.

version: '2.1'

```
services:
  z2padmin_docker:
    image: z2padmin_docker
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    volumes: [/home/ankit/Z2PDATAHUB/uploads:/mnt/Z2PDATAHUB/uploads]  
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    network_mode: host
```

Comment: `network_mode: host` isn't necessary for direct container-to-container communication.  The `docker-compose.yml` file shown in the original question should work (and if you read the comments, it does once you wait for MongoDB to start up).